# Running ElasticSearch as the root user

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm getting the error below when I try to start ElasticSearch 5.0 with `./elasticsearch`:

```
[2016-11-23T13:44:09,507][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    ... 6 more
```

I switched to another user and tried `sudo ./elasticsearch` and got the same error.

How do I start ElasticSearch as the root user?

Answer (score 30):

Elasticsearch can't be run an root user. Elasticsearch itself restricts this. A new user named elasticsearch and group named elasticsearch is automatically created when we install elasticsearch. Can check entries by using following commands

```
$ sudo less /etc/passwd | grep "elasticsearch"
$ sudo less /etc/group | grep "elasticsearch"
```

We need to change ownership of all [elasticsearch related files](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/directory-layout.html#_deb_and_rpm). Please follow the steps mentioned below.

Steps:

1.Change owership of all ES related files from root to elasticsearch using example cmd below.

```
$ sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /usr/share/elasticsearch
$ sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /var/log/elasticsearch
$ sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /var/lib/elasticsearch
$ sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /etc/default/elasticsearch
$ sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R /etc/elasticsearch
```

2.Open `/etc/default/elasticsearch` file and do the following things

```
  a)JAVA_HOME=your/java/home/path
  b)add the following entries at the end
      i)   START_DAEMON=true
      ii)  ES_USER=elasticsearch
      iii) ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
```

3.Now enable elasticsearch service and start

```
  $ sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
  $ sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
  $ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

4.Test elasticsearch by using curl. Say your host ip is 192.168.5.194 and ES running on port 9200

```
$ curl -X GET ‘192.168.5.194:9200’
```

DONE!!

Ref. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390311/1445978

Comment: Only step 1 was enough for me. I followed this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-22-04 and then did the permission changes mentioned in step 1 of this answer.

Comment: step 2  - for RPM system like  centOS, Rocky  - the default is in "/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearc"

Answer (score 10):

Root cause of this issue is:
ElasticSearch is not allowed to run from root owner. 
There is another possiblity for this issue "Java path is set for root user only not for all other users". 
Solution of this issue:

**Step 1:** Change the ownership of elasticSearch directory from root to other user by command.
**$sudo chown -R current_User:Group_Name elasticsearch-5.5.0**

**Setp 2:** Check Java set in classpath for current user[not only for root]. If command : **$java -version or echo $JAVA_HOME  command giving empty result. That means we should set Java in classpath [system env varible] for current user then Follow Step 3.** otherwise start elasticsearch service.

Step 3: Edit /etc/profile and add two lines as per your system dir
export JAVA_HOME="Java dir location"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
Run
$source source /etc/profile

After this run elasticSearch service. It worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**There are two ways to solve this problem :**

**Method1:**
download zip file n unzip then start by following command

```
bin/elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true -d
```

**Method2:**

```
vi bin/elasticsearch
```

Add property for allow root:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Des.insecure.allow.root=true"
```

Save and close.
**You can start by root now.**

Comment: In order for method 1 to work for me I had to add an -E flag before the setting change. `bin/eleasticsearch -E -Des.insecure.allow.root=true -d`

Comment: This workaround does not work anymore. Seems they just removed this option completely. It definitely doesn't work for ES 7.X. Maybe for some earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I had to connect with another user. But first, I had to grant him the rights to execute the bin/elasticsearch.

Comment: Consider posting this as comment instead or expand upon to include more details.

Answer (score 3):

A little late reply, but relevant still now.
I faced the same problem when i followed [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/deb.html), the last resort was to change the ownership of the folders which got un-zipped.

Just did `sudo chown <nonrootuser> <unzipped-es-folder> -R` does the trick.

P.S i was doing it on Ubuntu 17.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to run with `systemd` or as a **service** make sure that your `.service` file is running as user and group elasticsearch. You can specify your user and group under the Service field.

It's usually located in `/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service`:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process
User=elasticsearch
Group=elasticsearch
```

Comment: works like a charm, I am setting up second ES instances on the single box this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its a common mistake run bin/elasticsearch from the root folder.

Comment: Agreed. There is a reason ElasticSearch shouldn't run as root. Please refer to this document https://www.elastic.co/blog/bootstrap_checks_annoying_instead_of_devastating.  They did it to prevent support issue in production environment.  Some argued that they are running in docker environment, and it should be handled otherwise.  Please refer to this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-is-it-elasticsearch-is-not-allowed-to-run-as-root/60413  Bottom line. Be careful and understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why to run everything as a root user. Use a normal user instead of root user.

Switch to normal user and run it. If you don't have a any other user refer to [Linuxize document](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-users-in-linux-using-the-useradd-command/) on creating a user.

If you can't run it as a normal user then check the permissions for the file, Give complete access to the user over the file or folder using **chmod 777 <elastic_search_folder>**.

Please refer to [chmod wiki document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for further details.

If you want to use root user then do the following command from the elastic search folder.

```
./elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true
```

re-run the the elastic search. It should definately work.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked before for ES2 ([How to run Elasticsearch 2.1.1 as root user in Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920801/how-to-run-elasticsearch-2-1-1-as-root-user-in-linux-machine))

The same solution may work for 5.

As stated previously, you should probably not so this..

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate user without giving `sudo` privileges.
ex: `adduser elasticsearch`
then grant ownership of the folder to that user 
ex: `chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch elasticsearch-folder`
then switch to that user
ex: `su elasticsearch`
Now try running the service
ex: `./elasticsearch-xxx/bin/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 0):

`-Ees.insecure.allow.root` method did not work for me, as I was on version 7.9.0.

And I was too lazy to go for `chown` method, mentioned by [@Devasish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445978).

Instead, tried a bit lengthy one:

Create a non-root user for elastic-search:

```
ubuntu ~ # adduser elasticuser
```

Must use `adduser` command, not useradd.
`adduser` will auto-create the home directory.

Copy elastic-search folder from root's home-directory to elasticuser's home-directory:

```
ubuntu ~ # cp -R ./elasticsearch-7.9.0 /home/elasticuser/elasticsearch-7.9.0
```

Switch to the non-root user:

```
ubuntu ~ # su - elasticuser
```

Now, run elastic-search from the non-root user:

```
elasticuser@ubuntu ~ $ ./elasticsearch-7.9.0/bin/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

On centos 8,

```
adduser elasticuser
chown -R elasticuser:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/
chown -R elasticuser:elasticsearch /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
chown -R elasticuser:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch
chown -R elasticuser:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch/
chown -R elasticuser:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

To run elasticsearch:

```
su elasticuser
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```